# CSS: onclick for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

To fit images onto the screen width, I use **img{max-width:100%}** in the external CSS file. However on the mobile device (viewport **device-width** is used) images appear too small. I want *most of* them, when are clicked, to get original size, i.e. have their individual maxWidth property changed to "none", and if clicked again changed to "" to size back to 100% screen width. Two questions:

- is it possible to do using pure css?
- is it possible to set javascript routine to be called onclick for multiple images using CSS? Or any alternate solution (as I guess CSS can not change behavior)

The worst case I will have **onclick="func(this);"** for every img element to be processed, which is not so elegant as it could be I guess. Thank you.

Edit. Well there's another way - go through all the images after load and set their onclicks using javascript... is there better way?

Comment: just to clarify: "java" is to "javascript" what "car" is to "carpet"

Comment: javaSCRIPT... no idea why it was changed to Java...

Comment: a tagging typo i guess, nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Added a non-jQuery solution to my answer.

Comment: I just added a new version, that doesn't require adding an onclick on each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a small modification of another answer, **that takes into account the fact that you want this effect only for mobiles.** Of course, you could use **media queries** for applying different styles depending on the screen size; but you would still need some logic in order to do something on click events.

**CSS**

```
div{

    width:40px;
}

img{
    max-width:100%
}

.clicked{
       max-width:none !important;  
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').click(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 769){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Take a look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/7uKUs/

Also note that I'm considering a Mobile device any screen narrower than 769px. You can change this to apply to whatever logic you use for determining whether a device is a mobile or not.

And **here there's a solution without jQuery**, that requires each image to add an onclick function.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" onClick="toggleClass(this);"/>
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" onClick="toggleClass(this);" />
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" onClick="toggleClass(this);" />
</div
```

**Javascript**

```
  function toggleClass(obj){
    if(window.innerWidth < 769){ 
       if(obj.className.match(/\bclicked\b/)){
          obj.className = obj.className.replace('clicked', '');

       }else{
          obj.className += " clicked";
       }
    }
  }
```

**Single HTML solution that doesn't require 'onclick' on each image**

```
<div>
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" />
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" />
    <img  src="http://www.arvixe.com/images/landing_pages/jquery_hosting.png" />
</div>

<script>

    if(window.innerWidth < 769){
       var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
       for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
          elements[i].setAttribute('onclick','toggleClass(this)');
       }  
    }
    function toggleClass(obj){
          if(obj.className.match(/\bclicked\b/)){
             obj.className = obj.className.replace('clicked', ''); 
          }else{
             obj.className += " clicked";
          }
       }


</script>
```

The script must be added after all the images.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/L89m5/

Comment: Augusto and @Ishearer (both): this implementation requires inclusion of jQuery, without it I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Is it possible to do without jQuery? I guess yes as jQuery itself seem to be written in javascript (no idea BTW)?

Comment: And does !important really matter? I see it works without this flag set.

Comment: It's just for making sure it will not be overridden by other style rule.

Comment: I edited the answer giving an alternative non-jQuery solution at the bottom.

Comment: What is calling toggelClass? I put it in, nothing happens.

Comment: I edited the HTML code as well, to call this function on click event. Take a look at the Fiddle link I provided. I edited the answer for you to have all the code in one place.

Comment: Ah yes I see your example. This is what I want to eliminate - writing onclicks for every img element as there could be many of them, and all will require this onclick

Comment: Oh, I see... let me see what I can do.

Comment: Added a version that doesn't require you to specify an onclick value on each image.

Comment: Very similar to what I have implemented: __for(var i=0;i<document.images.length;i++){if(document.images[i].className.indexOf("res")==-1)document.images[i].onclick=function(){chs(this);}}__ res is a class which resets some properties of resizing images

Answer (score 1):

As far as a pure CSS implementation, the closest I can think of is wrapping each image in an anchor tag and using the `:active` state of the tag to change the CSS. This will only change the image **during** a click, though, and the style will revert once the click has completed.

(example: http://jsfiddle.net/kGs7Q/12/)

For a cleaner JavaScript implementation, you can use event delegation – handling all events once they bubble up to a common ancestor. This can be achieved easily with jQuery:

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://..."/>
    <img src="http://..."/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.image-wrapper').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); 
});
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper img {
    max-width: 120px;
}

.image-wrapper img.clicked {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

(example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh7L3/3/)